# WebRequest MVC HttpPost DateTime Format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, post, httpwebrequest

I have an MVC Action.....

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff(string myString, DateTime myDateTime)
```

...and I'm calling the action from a compact framework application like so.....

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Proxy = null;

        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "myString=Bonjour&myDateTime=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonPostData);

        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        // Get the request stream.
        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        // Get the response.
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            // Display the status.
            // Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Read the response...
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
```

Problem is the "myDateTime" parameter is always null?   What format should the postData string be in for this to work (i've tried quite a few!)?

Many thanks,

ETFairfax

Comment: The problem was spaces in the DateTime format.  Replaced with %20 and all is well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all a `DateTime` parameter **cannot** be null. This is a value type. Second of all you are writing too much code for such a simple task:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "myString", "Bonjour" },
        { "myDateTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") },
    };
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues(url, values);
    string strResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
}
```

Also notice that the parameter is called `myDateTime` in your controller action so you must send exactly this parameter name.

Comment: WebClient not available on Compact Framework, and the fact that null is being assigned to the DateTime is the problem!!!!

Comment: Using the format string "yyyy-MM-dd" seems to have fixed it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think your postData string is wrong. It should be:

```
string postData = "myString=Bonjour&myDateTime=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

More Info: ASP.NET MVC's parameter binding to arguments in a controller action will match on the name of the values posted or in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Did you misspell? You are posting 'myDate', but your action method expects 'myDateTime'.